# Extract Sum of 'Revenue' from Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, curl

I have an array which is a lis, how would I sum the revenue from the specific dates? Please see code below or here https://3v4l.org/eUavL

Like this:

2018-10-28-29.02 USD

2018-10-29-34.73 USD

2018-10-30-27.22 USD

== Sum 90.97 USD

Thanks so much from help!!

```
<?php

$curl_response = '{
"options": {
    "ranking_metric": "paid_impressions",
    "time_interval": "day",
    "report_type": "time",
    "filters": {
        "pid": "2759"
    },
    "data_source": "detailed",
    "format": "json",
    "end_date": "2018-10-28 23:59",
    "columns": ["paid_impressions", "revenue"],
    "time_zone": "UTC",
    "start_date": "2018-10-26 00:00"
},
"api_url": "http://udmserve.com/udm/radalytics_api.cpx?action=report&api_key=xxxx&api_key=xxxx",
"time": 1540989662,
"rows": [{
    "paid_impressions": "18136",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-26 00:00",
    "_combined_val": "",
    "ranking_col": "49046",
    "revenue": "28.461629999999985",
    "rank": "1",
    "f0_": ""
}, {
    "paid_impressions": "14432",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-27 00:00",
    "_combined_val": "",
    "ranking_col": "49046",
    "revenue": "25.707970000000017",
    "rank": "1",
    "f0_": ""
}, {
    "paid_impressions": "16478",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-28 00:00",
    "_combined_val": "",
    "ranking_col": "49046",
    "revenue": "29.07676000000002",
    "rank": "1",
    "f0_": ""
}]
}';

 $array = json_decode($curl_response,true);
foreach($array['rows'] as $arr){
    echo explode(' ',$arr['timestamp'])[0].'-'.number_format((float)$arr['revenue'], 2, '.', '').' USD'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Code also here: https://3v4l.org/eUavL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a running total as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5PvFr))

```
$array = json_decode($curl_response,true);
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array['rows'] as $set) {
    $sum += $revenue = number_format((float)$set['revenue'], 2, '.', '');
    echo explode(' ', $set['timestamp'])[0] , "-$revenue USD\n";
}
echo "\t== " , number_format((float)$sum, 2, '.', '') , " USD";
```

Output:

```
2018-10-26-28.46 USD
2018-10-27-25.71 USD
2018-10-28-29.08 USD
        == 83.25 USD
```

*note, this keeps adding the number_formatted values.  If you require higher specificity -- that is, you want to add up the longer float values and then only format the total once at the end, I can code that up too.

Comment: The link to your demo is broken.

Comment: I just noticed that StackOverflow has a new link inserter.  Something is weird. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed.  It seems that it didn't clear the `https://` when I pasted.  This was not the default behavior with the prior hyperlink insert field.  ...the `https://` used to be highlighted so that when I ctrl-v, the string is overwritten.  Now I have to highlight the text before pasting.  It also appears that with the posting upgrade, that edits prior to 5 minutes are now being recorded.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great!!